# Remove post_id from WordPress permalink and redirect old url's to new url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

I have posts URL's like `/%category%/%post_id%-%postname%/` in the permalink.

Now I want to remove `post_id` from the the permalink like `/%category%/%postname%/` .

How can I do it in WordPress without getting 404 error.
**(I had some past email campaigns,so it was with old url's.)**

Like Old URL:

http://example.com/category/4390-new-post/

New URL:

http://example.com/category/new-post/

I have more than 70,000 posts on site. so I could not add 301 redirection for all the posts.

please help.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your permalinks - that's an easy fix with no redirects involved. here's a link to read more: https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

in your WP-Admin , go to **Settings > Permalinks** and apply which option you'd like.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I sent some url's in email campaign so what about those. Its goes to 404.